# Error in Adding data to Cloud FireStore - "Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, firebase, express, asynchronous, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble adding data to the Cloud Firestore Database.

This is a function, specifically a cloud function, written in node JS, that adds some data to the online cloud Firestore database, as seen in my code sample below.

I'm getting this **error** : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`

In a crux,
**lang**      :  Node.JS 
**purpose**   : Add data to firestore DB 
**Error**     : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'collection' of undefined`

**JS CODE**

```node-js
const { initializeApp, applicationDefault, cert } = require('firebase-admin/app');
const { getFirestore, Timestamp, FieldValue } = require('firebase-admin/firestore');

initializeApp();
const db = getFirestore();

async function testAddData(db) {

    const docRef = db.collection('users').doc('alovelace');

    await docRef.set({
        first: 'Ada',
        last: 'Lovelace',
        born: 1815
    });

    const aTuringRef = db.collection('users').doc('aturing');

    await aTuringRef.set({
        'first': 'Alan',
        'middle': 'Mathison',
        'last': 'Turing',
        'born': 1912
    });

}

module.exports = { testAddData };
```

Can someone please guide me where I'm coding it wrong...

Comment: Can you add where you are calling `testAddData` to your question?

Comment: The error seems to provide a clue - you're attempting to read a property `collection` from the `db` object which appears to be undefined. Did you check your code to ensure `db` is being initialized correctly?